# IDP Initiated Login

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I'm trying to implement an IDP Initiated login in my company, we hire a platform that generates a SAML XML response for me and posts it to my backend (.NET Core 3.1).

This SAML Response is a Base64 hash and has already been converted to XML. The lib has some specific method to deal with SAML response in this scenario?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is more or less the samme as the TestWebAppCore sample expect to recive in the [AssertionConsumerService method](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/Controllers/AuthController.cs#L49). The code show a post binding, you can change it to redirect if the authn response is send as a query parameter.

```
var binding = new Saml2PostBinding();
var saml2AuthnResponse = new Saml2AuthnResponse(config);

binding.ReadSamlResponse(Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(), saml2AuthnResponse);
if (saml2AuthnResponse.Status != Saml2StatusCodes.Success)
{
    throw new AuthenticationException($"SAML Response status: {saml2AuthnResponse.Status}");
}
binding.Unbind(Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(), saml2AuthnResponse);
await saml2AuthnResponse.CreateSession(HttpContext, claimsTransform: (claimsPrincipal) => ClaimsTransform.Transform(claimsPrincipal));

var relayStateQuery = binding.GetRelayStateQuery();
//var some_value = relayStateQuery.ContainsKey("some_key");
return Redirect("...some_url...");
```